# Confused about why an Elixir Ecto validation test is not working

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a user model that looks like this:

```rb
defmodule MyApp.User do
  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string

    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_confirmation, :string, virtual: true

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(name email)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 8)
  end
end
```

And the test in question makes sure the password length validation works.

```rb
defmodule MyApp.UserTest do
  use MyApp.ModelCase

  alias MyApp.User
  alias MyApp.Repo

  @valid_attrs %{
    name: "Uli Kunkel",  
    email: "nihilist@example.com", 
  }

  @invalid_attrs %{}

  test "validates the password is the correct length" do
    attrs = @valid_attrs |> Map.put(:password, "1234567")
    changeset = %User{} |> User.changeset(attrs)
    assert {:error, changeset} = Repo.insert(changeset)
  end
end
```

Only the test fails, even though the password is a character too short.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're rejecting the `password` field when creating the changeset. 
This makes it so the validation on that field is not even triggered.

You need to add `password` to either your `@required_fields` or `@optional_fields` list.

Comment: Ah, that's it!  Thank you. I was looking at the changeset with IEx.pry before, seeing the password value in params section, and getting confused.  Now that I look at it again, I can see how it's included in the params but not the changes.  Interesting.  I'm sure this will bite me again. :)

Comment: Yes, we need to find a way to warn if a field has been given to the changeset but not used.

Comment: I am having the same issue.. I have added `password` to `@required_fields` and added this too `|> validate_length(:password, min: 6)` But still no luck yet.. password is still passing `1` as correct password